# How to perform RDF ontology matching

Tags: rdf, sparql, jena, ontology, rdflib

What is the best way to perform the matching between two ontologies so that I can get a similarity score between the two ontologies which can make the job of integration easy (integration of data from different RDF)

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @ankita singh, I have rolled back your edit of this question, because you changed it into a completely different question. The answers given below were not for this new, different question and therefore no longer made any sense. If you have a new question, please post it *as a new question* - do not edit an existing one to change its meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways of mapping triples to an ontology. You can do it in [Protégé](http://protege.stanford.edu/), use SPARQL constructs, SWRL rules or do it with a programming library like Jena and RDFlib. 
I would choose the approach you are most familiar with. If that is Jena, I would do that. 
There you can use several of Jena's mapping functions to do most of the work for you. 
Just check the [Jena API](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/) for reference.

Personally I think the best way and the most safest way is to use Protégé, but for a quicker and more hackier solution a SPARQL contruct might work. Like this example:

```
CONSTRUCT {
    ?lexicon vso:fuelType ?fuel .
    ?fuel a gr:QualitativeValue .
} WHERE {
    [ co:lexicon ?lexicon ;
        co:confVarId "PT1628" ;
        co:hasValue ?fuel ] .
}
```

Here I want to turn a lexicon entry into a Qualitative value object and set the lexicon to have a property fuelType to this object.

Comment: Thanks a lot but I wanted to have mapping between two ontologies such that I can have similarity score between two ontologies.

Comment: Ok. Post links to the definition of both ontologies or try to explain them. Also for future references you should also add that you want to calculate the similarity score between the ontologies right away. I see you have done it now.